# Relation $\Delta x \Delta p \approx \hbar$. Show that the condition $\Delta p \ll p$ guarantees that the packet does not spread

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, time-evolution

Consider a wave packet that satisfies the relation $\Delta x \Delta p \approx \hbar$. Show that the condition $\Delta p \ll p$ guarantees that the packet does not spread appreciably in the time it takes to pass through a fixed point.

I know that the condition for little spread of the wavepacket is

$$(k-k_o)^2 \frac{\hbar}{m}t \ll 1 \approx (\Delta k)^2 \frac{\hbar}{m}t \ll 1$$

However, I am unable to get this result from the conditions provided. Is this the right condition?

Comment: In QM $p$ is an operator whereas $\Delta p$ is a real number. What do you mean by $\Delta p \ll p$?

Comment: sorry $p$ is the momentum of the particle, and $\Delta p$ is the uncertainty in the momentum.